# How to wait until API has finished get request and appended variables before loading viewController

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, foundation, urlsession

I have some helpers that do an Alamofire getRequest to an API, and then fill some arrays which I need in order for the next ViewController to display the correct information. I call the requests in appDelegate here:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    CGCoins.shared.getData { (arr) in

    }

    CGExchange.shared.getData { (arr) in

    }

    CGPrices.shared.getData { (arr) in

    }
```

But they take some time to complete and the ViewController loads before this leading to a crash, or empty labels etc. Here is how the helpers look inside:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

 class CGCoins {

static let shared = CGCoins()

var ids: [String] = []
var symbols: [String] = []
var names: [String] = []

var coinDictionary: [String : String] = [:]

var defaultCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DefaultCurrency")

func getData(completion:@escaping(_ arr:[Type])->()) {
    /// alamofire / urlsession request
    let url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in


        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            // Do whatever here
            return

        case .success(let data):
            // First make sure you got back a dictionary if that's what you expect
            let responseJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if responseJSON.count != 0 {

                //do whatever you want with your object json

                parse(json: responseJSON)
            }
        }

}
/// after finish completion(arr)
func parse(json: JSON) {
    for result in json[].arrayValue {
        let id = result["id"].stringValue
        let symbol = result["symbol"].stringValue
        let name = result["name"].stringValue

        ids.append(id)
        symbols.append(symbol)
        names.append(name)

        for (index, element) in ids.enumerated() {
            coinDictionary[element] = symbols[index]
        }


    }

}


}

}
```

A pageViewController and ViewController use this data. I tried to create a second splash screen after launch and call the get requests there, but how can I make it not push to the pageViewController until the get requests have finished?

Comment: You can use `DispatchGroup` to synchronize the requests. By the way **never ever** use multiple arrays as data source. Use a custom struct or class and decode the JSON with `Codable`. SwiftyJSON has become obsolete in Swift 4

Comment: @vadian Thank you, how would I better structure it instead of using multiple arrays? at the moment I have 3 swift files set up in a similar way that get different data into arrays that I then use, would it be possible to get an example of how I should be doing it? Thank you

Comment: Just use a `struct Item { let name, id, symbol : String }` – or whatever name you like –,   declare **one** array `var items = [Item]()` and create instances in `parse` `items.append(Item(name: name, id: id, symbol: symbol))` or as mentioned decode the JSON directly into the struct with the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: @vadian Okay, so i will use a struct instead of the current arrays, will i still be able to create the dictionary that consists of for example the name and the image url? Can you expand a bit on the dispatchGroup, I am not sure what is wrong but maybe it is the way the completion works in the functions, but the dispatchGroup doesnt seem to do anything, as i dont understand how to get the api call to let it know that everything is complete and, parsing is done etc.

Comment: Today I wrote an answer related to `DispatchGroup`. [Please have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126494/swift-force-synchronous-execution-of-work-and-subsequent-ui-rendering/52126545#52126545).

Comment: @vadian that helped thank you, got it working.