# calling synchronously with alamofire Swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have an array that has a list of strings, and I should call API to translate it. in my current case, the response of API is coming after the for loop done, I need to call the API one by one. I mean I need to wait for the response to send the other string.
Here is my code

```
var stringList = ["cat","dog","cup","glass","land"]

for k in 0..< stringList.count {
     self.SetTranslateLetters(WORD: stringList[k], LANG: "AR", completionHandler: { (true) in

    })
}

func SetTranslateLetters(WORD: String, LANG:String, completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let param: [String:AnyObject] = [
        "word": WORD as AnyObject,
        "language":LANG as AnyObject
    ]
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.manager-response-queue",
                              qos: .userInitiated,
                              attributes:.concurrent)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,
        parameters: param,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"]).responseJSON(queue: queue, options: .allowFragments,
                 completionHandler: { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

                    switch(response.result) {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print("done")
                        let json_ = JSON(value)
                        // print(json_)


                        let getCoun = json_["TranslateResult"]
                        // print(getCoun)


                        break
                    case .failure(_):
                        print(response.result.error!)
                        if response.result.error?._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut{
                            //TODO: Show Alert view on netwok connection.
                            completionHandler(true)

                        }
                        break
                    }
    })

}
```

Comment: Don't wait. Use `DispatchGroup`. And `param` is clearly `[String:String]`, this avoids also the ugly `as AnyObject` bridge cast.

Comment: can you give me example please

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126494/swift-force-synchronous-execution-of-work-and-subsequent-ui-rendering/52126545#52126545

Comment: Conventions in Swift are to use camel case for function names: `setTranslateLetters` instead of `SetTranslateLetters`. I recommend you to use [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) to enforce yourself with improved practices.

Comment: @vadian actually i'm confusing, how can i put it in my code. thanks in advance

Comment: The answer In the linked question is pretty straightforward. Create the group, in the loop before the asynchronous line call `enter`, in the completion handler call `leave`. after the loop call `notify`. It's crucial that the `enter`/`leave` pairs are balanced.

Comment: Just to be clear: "calling synchronously". Don't do it synchronously. If you can have all the items called concurrently, you can use simply the DispatchGroup (with enter, leave and notify). If not, you might want to use a recursive call for instance.