# running a nested Alamofire request synchronously

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to retrieve data from my node by making requests multiple times (to get the distance a car travels). However it seems that the executiono is not occuring in the right order. I believe this is due to the fact that the requests are not processed synchronously.

I have looked at other questions but it doesnt seem to fit my situation because of the nested requests.

var d1: Double!
    var d2: Double!
    var d3: Double!
    var d4: Double!

```
var speed: Double!
var speed1: Double!

@objc func getSpeed() {

    Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/speed", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let result = response.result.value as! [String:Any]? {
            if let response = result["data"] as! [String: Any]?
            {
                self.d1 = response["distance"] as? Double
                print("First distance is \(self.d1) KM")
                //Delay for 5 secods
                sleep(5)
                //Make the call again.
                Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/speed", method: .get).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

                    if let result = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
                        if let response = result["data"] as! [String:Any]?
                        {
                            self.d2 = response["distance"] as? Double
                            print("The second distance is \((self.d2)!)")
                            let distance = self.d2 - self.d1
                            print("The total distance for the first part is \(distance)")
                            self.speed = (distance / 5) * 1000
                            print("\((self.speed)!) is the speed (m/s) for the first part")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    sleep(30)
    Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/speed", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let result = response.result.value as! [String:Any]? {
            if let response = result["data"] as! [String: Any]?
            {
                self.d3 = response["distance"] as? Double
                print("The third distance is \((self.d3)!)")
                //Delay for 5 secods
                sleep(5)
                //Make the call again.
                Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/speed", method: .get).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

                    if let result = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
                        if let response = result["data"] as! [String:Any]?
                        {
                            self.d4 = response["distance"] as? Double
                            print("The fourth distance is \((self.d4)!)")
                            let distance = self.d4 - self.d3
                            print("The total distance for the second part is \(distance)")
                            self.speed = (distance / 5) * 1000
                            print("\((self.speed)!) is the speed (m/s) for the second part")
                        }
                    }})
            }
        }
    }
    if speed1 == 0 && speed > 90 {
        //Wait 5 minutes to see if the car moves
        sleep(30)
        if speed1 == 0 {
            //Send SMS
            Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/message?long=longitude&lat=lat", method: .get).responseJSON { _ in}
        }
    }else {
        print("There is no issue")
    }
}
```

I am running the below function every 5 minutes or so in my appdelegate,

Comment: That's horrible. Please don't do that. There are APIs like Grand Central Dispatch which are able to maintain the order of asynchronous network requests. And please don't *force unwrap an optional to an optional* (`as! [String: Any]?`). If you want to conditional downcast the proper syntax is `as? [String: Any]`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Alamofire. This is for a small project, nothing major, is there no work around?

Comment: You can use GCD together with Alamofire. GCD is a mechanism to control threads and tasks

Comment: Can you please illustrate how I would go about editing my code.

Comment: Please search for `DispatchGroup` for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126494/swift-force-synchronous-execution-of-work-and-subsequent-ui-rendering/52126545#52126545

Comment: I am familiar with GCD I am just not sure how to integrate it with my existing code.